# Prove: If a linear function mapping ${\rm I\!R}^{K}$ into itself is onto then it is also one-to-one.

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I have been trying to prove this statement but it is escaping me.

If T is a linear function from ${\rm I\!R}^{K}$ to ${\rm I\!R}^{K}$, then if T is onto the T is one-to-one.

I can see why if I think of the K=1 case, with a straight line passing through the origin, but I can't find the way to build the proof.

Thank you!

Comment: If $T$ is onto, then for any $1\leq j \leq K$ there exists $v_j\in\mathbb{R}^K$ such that $T(v_j)=e_j$. Can you use this fact to develop a formula for $T^{-1}$?

Comment: The book I am using does not really use inverse functions nor matrices (which are not even defined yet) so I would rather take an approach not involving $T^{-1}$

Comment: That "R" is really cool looking. How did you produce it?

Comment: Thanks. Click on 'edit' to see the source and from there you can simply copy it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From Axler's Linear Algebra Done Right:

> 3.2 Proposition: Let $T \in \mathcal{L}(V, W)$. Then $T$ is injective if and only if null $T=\{0\}$.

> PROOF: First suppose that $T$ is injective. We want to prove that null $T=\{0\}$. We already know that {0}$\subset$ null $T$ (by 3.1). To prove the inclusion in the other direction, suppose $v \in$ null $T$. Then
> $$
> T(v)=0=T(0)
> $$
> Because $T$ is injective, the equation above implies that $v=0$. Thus null $T=\{0\},$ as desired.
> To prove the implication in the other direction, now suppose that null $T=\{0\}$. We want to prove that $T$ is injective. To do this, suppose $u, v \in V$ and $T u=T v .$ Then
> $$
> 0=T u-T v=T(u-v)
> $$
> Thus $u-v$ is in $\operatorname{null} T,$ which equals $\{0\} .$ Hence $u-v=0,$ which implies that $u=v$. Hence $T$ is injective, as desired.

---

If $Tv=0$ for some nonzero $v \in \mathbb R^k$ (i.e., if $T$ is not one-to-one, by Proposition 3.2), writing $v = v_1e_1 + \cdots + v_ke_k$ ($e_j$ is the vector whose only nonzero entry is a $1$ in the $j$-th place) we have that $$0 = v_1Te_1 + \cdots + v_kTe_k,$$ that is, the vectors $Te_1,\dots,Te_k$ are linearly dependent. Thus $Te_1,\dots,Te_k$ cannot span $\mathbb R^k$ (why?), meaning that $T$ cannot be onto.

Comment: Could you elaborate on why stating ``$Tv=0$ for some nonzero $v \in \mathbb R^k$'' is equivalent to negating that $T$ is one-to-one''?

Comment: I use this definition from Axler (1997) ``A linear map $T: V \rightarrow W$ is called injective if whenever $u, v \in V$ and $T u=T v,$ we have $u=v .$''

Comment: So a linear map $T: V \rightarrow W$ is **not** injective (or one-to-one) if there exists $u, v \in V$ such that $T u \neq T v$, but $u=v$. You suppose that there exists a $v \in \mathbb{R}^{k}$ mapping to $0$ and I am not seeing how this negates T one-to-one. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Ooooh, I see now! Thank you very much! I am just going to edit you answer so that it fully explains every step (for the use of future users).

Comment: @FabioI. Your welcome!

Comment: I know why then $T e_{1}, \ldots, T e_{k} \text { cannot span } \mathbb{R}^{k}$ but reporting the proof for it would have been too lengthy :D

Comment: @FabioI. That's it a basic result also: if $V$ is a finite-dimensional vector space and $v_1,\dots,v_{\dim V}$ are linearly independent (resp. they spans $V$) then they spans $V$ (resp. they are linearly independent).

Comment: A further comment: where you write $0= v_1Te_1 + \cdots + v_kTe_k$ shouldn't you specify that at least one $\{v_1, \cdots, v_k\}$ is non-zero? For linear dependence

Comment: Well, that's implicit when we say that $v$ is nonzero.